# NSError error code -11819 on iOS when trying to play media using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

When trying to play the media url using AVPlayer, I get AVPlayerStatusFailed with error code -11819. Please advise.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change: (NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
  if (context == &AVPlayerItemStatusContext) {
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
    NSInteger status = [playerItem status];
    switch (status) {
        case AVPlayerStatusFailed:
        {
            NSError *error = [playerItem error];
            NSLog(@"%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, [error code]);
            .....
        }
  ....
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found in AVError.h that AVFoundation error code -11819 corresponds to AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset ("The operation could not be completed because media services became unavailable").